# Hello world program crashes in gtkmm

Tags: c++, windows-7, mingw, gtkmm

I am trying to get gtkmm working on Windows 7 with MinGW. But, when after I compile the hello world program from the [gtkmm-tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.22/gtkmm-tutorial.html#sec-helloworld), the exe just crashes with a segfault.

I've compiled the program with this:

```
$ g++ helloworld.cc main.cc -o hw `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-2.4`
```

Here's what gdb shows:

```
$ gdb hw.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from c:\dev/hw.exe...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: c:\dev/hw.exe
[New Thread 4348.0x1560]
[New Thread 4348.0x1430]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x664d85b2 in Glib::ObjectBase::ObjectBase (this=0x47453c, __vtt_parm=0x1,
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at objectbase.cc:49
49      objectbase.cc: No such file or directory.
```

I'm a bit newbie, so I don't know how to get it to work.

I've downloaded gtkmm from [here](https://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/MSWindows#gtkmm) (the 2.22 version) and the g++'s version:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\Mingw\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/lto-wrappe
r.exe
Target: i686-pc-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-gmp=/c/temp/g
cc/gmp --with-mpfr=/c/temp/gcc/mpfr --with-mpc=/c/temp/gcc/mpc --enable-language
s=c,c++ --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-n
ls --disable-shared --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-win32-registry --enable-
checking=release --enable-lto
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.1 (GCC)
```

Do I need something more? or I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: You'll want to issue the `bt` command (BackTrace) in GDB after the segfault, to find out what line of your code triggered it. Also, did you copy-paste the program or type it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

It seems MinGW [made an ABI change with GCC 4.7.0](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/MinGW-GCC-4-7-0-released-tt7578133.html). If your gtkmm was compiled with an earlier GCC, this would cause problems like you are seeing.  Try rebuilding gtkmm with the same compiler.

Comment: Ok, that means I need to compile GTK+, giomm and pangomm. It will take me a while to compile those libraries, since I don't have so much time to get them working. Thanks for the answer.